# mysql add column added question mark after name

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I added a column to an existing mysql table using:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columnname varchar(10) AFTER anothercolumnname;
```

When I did a

```
DESCRIBE tablename;
```

The added column looked like

```
columnname?
```

I am unable to drop the column to try and re-add it, and after I did this I realized I did not use quotes for the names. Is there any way to remove that column? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should remove the column; use bacticks to escape the table name:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP column `columnname?`;
```

But are you certain that you did not accidentally enter a question mark when you added the column?

Comment: drop table just worked for me, i must have forgotten the backticks when i wasa trying to drop earlier, thank you very much

Comment: So then the column name really ended in a question mark?

Comment: It did, no idea why it inserted with a question mark in the first place